# Gradle - Use other version of dependency in Unit Tests

Tags: java, android, gradle, threetenbp

In a pure Java module, I have a dependency to `compile group: 'org.threeten', name: 'threetenbp', version: threeTenVersion, classifier: 'no-tzdb'`. I'm using the `no-tzdb` variant because this module will be used inside an Android app and the the tzdb will be added by the Android module.

However, in my unit tests, I would like to be able to call some methods like `DateTime.now()` which requires ThreeTen to be initializd with a tzdb.

I would like to know if there is a way to use another version of the library only during unit tests so that I can use the version with the tzdb installed ?

I already tried the following :

```
compile group: 'org.threeten', name: 'threetenbp', version: threeTenVersion, classifier: 'no-tzdb'
    testCompile "org.threeten:threetenbp:threeTenVersion"
```

But the `no-tzdb` is still used.

Thank you,
Pierre

Comment: Have you tried marking threeTen for your tests as 'testRuntime'? See the [following](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

Comment: Actually it just works the way I tried, it was just Android Studio that was not understanding the new testCompile line I added to the build script. I restarted the IDE and it runned perfectly ... Strange ... Thank you anyway

Comment: also, you can build a tzdb only jar that you can add to your testCompile config: http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/update-tzdb.html

Comment: Yeah gradle can be finicky like that. I seem to remember running into this issue in the past. What IDE do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is relevant in your case, but one approach to consider:

1. If you're not already using [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (ThreeTen *Android* Backport), which efficiently initialises timezone information on Android, switch to using it.
2. *In your unit tests*, use the original JVM backport ([threetenbp](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp)).

I was inspired by https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP/issues/14 to try the JVM backport in tests, and it works for me.

So in `build.gradle` I have:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.4' 

// For unit tests involving ThreeTen, use JVM backport instead of Android one
testCompile('org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp', module: 'threetenabp'
}
```

With this setup, in my unit tests, methods like `ZonedDateTime.now()` and `OffsetDateTime.now()` work fine. (There is no type called `DateTime` in ThreeTen.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mockito, you can mock a Context and AssetManager so AndroidThreeTen loads your test project's version of TZDB.dat. Something like:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Context mockContext = mock(Context.class);
    AssetManager mockAssets = mock(AssetManager.class);
    when(mockAssets.open(anyString())).thenReturn(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("TZDB.dat"));
    when(mockContext.getAssets()).thenReturn(mockAssets);
    AndroidThreeTen.init(mockContext);
}
```

Make sure to put your `TZDB.dat` in `src/test/resources/TZDB.dat`

If you're looking for `TZDB.dat` it can be found here after you've built your project:
`project_directory/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.jakewharton.threetenabp/threetenabp/1.0.4/assets/org/threeten/bp/TZDB.dat`